# Generate the EDMX backing files in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: edmx, ef-database-first, visual-studio-2019, database-first

After modifying an EDMX in Visual Studio 2019, it saves the EDMX properly but does not generate the C# files.

This is a database first functionality, is there a new trick in VS2019 to actually generate the C# files on save?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to write a feedback to Microsoft but the same question is asked on their network. The issue was

> VS 2019 Preview2-Preview 4.2 after saving EDMX code is not generated

It is marked as resolved for VS2019 16.1

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/705

It is also mentioned in the bug that you may run the custom tools manually on all the EDMX, and *.tt files to generate your templates. And this works.

[image]